# Displaying blank if there is only two words in a column, and only displaying the third word

Tags: mysql

So I am struggling getting an if statement working with a `substring_index` statement that meets the requirements that I am looking for. I have a column called "product_name" that lists the names of all of my products, and the goal is to look at each string, determine if there is less than three words in the string. If there is, display the string as blank, if there is a third word, show only the third word (and if there are more than 3 words, only display the third word hiding everything else).

I hope that this makes sense.

So far I have a substring index that can find the first and second word based on checking `' '`'s in the string, however I am unsure of how to form an if statement to analyze the string and display blank if there are only two words.

I haven't made it to the part of singling out the third word yet. Below is that code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT substring_index(product_name, ' ', 1) AS a,
       substring_index(product_name, ' ', 2) AS b 
FROM products
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `case` and substring index -- assuming words are separated by exactly one space:

```
select (case when product_name not like '% % %' then ''
             else substring_index(substring_index(product_name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1)
        end)
```

Comment: Holy smokes, you made that look so easy. A friend also mentioned using case, I just hadn't taken the time to look into it as I figured I could get it done with an if and substring index statement. THANK YOU!